# Using LDAP/AD, how can I get a user's timezone?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am looking for a standard way to find a user's timezone from LDAP, is there a standard way to do that? What kind of query would it be?

Here is the user data that I have:

```
{ dn: 'CN=alexamil,OU=Employees,OU=Wisco Users,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
  controls: [],
  objectClass: [ 'top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user' ],
  cn: 'alexamil',
  sn: 'Stills',
  c: 'US',
  title: 'Engineer - Software',
  description: 'Chuck Stills',
  givenName: 'Chuck',
  distinguishedName: 'CN=alexamil,OU=Employees,OU=Wisco Users,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
  instanceType: '4',
  whenCreated: '20170218230806.0Z',
  whenChanged: '20170510101002.0Z',
  displayName: 'Chuck Stills -T (alexamil - FANDTAD AMERICA LP at Wisco)',
  uSNCreated: '231725435',
  memberOf:
   [ 'CN=adam-generic-owners-ad-stage,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=jenkins_ci4_mailer,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=lae-aci-mig-may6,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=anyconnect_vpn_users,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=group.temp.gpotter,OU=Organizational,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=cdt-dev,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=itai-msa,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=all-ex-emear,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=global-ex-emear,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=group.allcwk.gpotter,OU=Organizational,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=staff.allcwk.gpotter,OU=Organizational,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=crashplan-west,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=icf-guest,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=global-all,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=staff.gpotter,OU=Organizational,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=group.gpotter,OU=Organizational,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=coreswgroup_r,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=cits_sj_all,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=dept-020070150,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=us.nonhq.emps,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=us.all,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=contr-americas-theatre,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=group-all-stirumal,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=us-all,OU=Mailer,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=cvcmsales,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=wwsparch,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=it-all,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=it_all,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=it-ebc,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=gts_afs,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=englearn-wisco,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=engguest,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=dpt70150,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=cpe_scm,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=corp700s,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=ccbuguest,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=watchit,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=owtallusers,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=owt370-r,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=ibsgit,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=corp_all,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=crrq-access,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=wiscoall,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=c2users,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=c2cusers,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
     'CN=allusers,OU=Grouper,OU=Wisco Groups,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com' ],
  uSNChanged: '242363538',
  co: 'United States',
  department: '020070150',
  company: 'Wisco Systems, Inc.',
  employeeType: 'Temp',
  name: 'alexamil',
  objectGUID: '^\'��\b\n�I���\u0002\u0006^��',
  userAccountControl: '512',
  badPwdCount: '0',
  codePage: '0',
  countryCode: '0',
  employeeID: '471533',
  badPasswordTime: '0',
  lastLogoff: '0',
  lastLogon: '0',
  scriptPath: 'cscoadls.vbs',
  pwdLastSet: '131320857116769174',
  primaryGroupID: '513',
  objectSid: '\u0001\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005\u0015\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007�;+��\u00151C\u0017\n2֕%\u0000',
  accountExpires: '9223372036854775807',
  logonCount: '0',
  sAMAccountName: 'alexamil',
  sAMAccountType: '805306368',
  userPrincipalName: 'alexamil@dev.wisco.com',
  lockoutTime: '0',
  objectCategory: 'CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
  dSCorePropagationData: '16010101000000.0Z',
  mail: 'alexamil@wisco.com',
  manager: 'CN=chridema,OU=Employees,OU=Wisco Users,DC=dev,DC=wisco,DC=com',
  gidNumber: '55999',
  wiscoITWkrAccGrantDate: '2017/04/30 00:00:00',
  wiscoITWkrWorkDesc: 'RANDSTAD NORTH AMERICA LP',
  gecos: 'Chuck Stills',
  wiscoITWkrAccEndDate: '2017/07/29 00:00:00',
  unixHomeDirectory: '/users/alexamil',
  wiscoITStatus: 'Active',
  wiscoITWkrAccDesc: '00002',
  wiscoITManagerUid: '383576',
  wiscoITDescription: 'GATS IT Acquisition Integration US OPEX',
  uidNumber: '472533',
  loginShell: '/bin/bash',
  wiscoITWkrAcc: '00002',
  wiscoITWkrAccGrantBy: 'chridema' }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The timezone is a local machine setting stored in the registry.  It wouldn't make much sense to store it with the user account.

Edit:

LDAP is the standardized protocol implemented by all modern directory servers. AD is a product family from Microsoft. Your user account is stored in AD DS, but your timezone settings are stored in your system registry. You can access your user account via LDAP.  You can access your machine's timezone settings via WMI, for example.

Comment: Thanks, hmmm so is there a way to retrieve that timezone data from LDAP even if it's not attached to the user?

Comment: But the computer's registry isn't stored in Active Directory, so, how should that be possible short of extending AD functionality?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything about LDAP/AD, I don't even know what the difference is